# Can not install cocoa pods in OSX 10.10.5

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa

I got this error while trying the command "**sudo gem install cocoapods**" on OSX 10.10.5  **"invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**: (some path for a file)".
 I am trapped in this for some days.Can not proceed because my new project needs cocoa pods.Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced same issue some days ago. **What I did was "just remove the file referenced in "some path for a file""**, and retry installing cocoa pods.

Just try this:

On command line type these

```
  sudo rm "<some path for a file>"

  sudo gem install cocoapods .
```

Now you can install cocoa pod.